# Mysql query is not fetching data as i want

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get records from 2 tables, query working but not returning as i want.

I want show all users who have id in t1.msg_from and order by t1.msg_status (status value is 0 and 1)

like first all status have value = 0 and then 1

```
 SELECT t1.msg_status, t2.ID, t2.username
 FROM messages t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN users t2 ON t1.msg_from=t2.ID
 GROUP BY t2.ID ORDER BY t1.msg_status ASC
```

Comment: What purpose does your `GROUP BY` clause serve here? It's possible you want `ORDER BY` instead.  Please make sure you really do want `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Post sample data and the desired output.  Your description is confusing.

Comment: Group by for user to prevent multiple record.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you wnat... Can you provide some data sample and desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.msg_status, u.id, u.username
from messages m
join users u on m.msg_from = u.id
order by u.id, m.msg_status
```

I'm guessing the above is probably what you want.  The problem with having a group by before your order by is that you essentially collapse everything to the single user id and by that point it's sort of a guessing game as to which one mysql will put into the status field.  So by the time it get's to the order by part of your query there is nothing left for it to order because you've collapsed it down to a single record per user id.

--

If you're looking for a count of statuses per user id then you could modify it slightly like so:

```
select count(*), m.msg_status, u.id, u.username
from messages m
join users u on m.msg_from = u.id
group by u.id, m.msg_status
```

**UPDATE**

```
drop table if exists messages;
create table messages (
  message_id INT(15),
  message VARCHAR(100),
  msg_from INT(15),
  msg_status INT(1)
  );
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int(15),
  username varchar(50)
  );

insert into users values
(55, 'John Doe'),
(66, 'Paul Hopkins'),
(77, 'Mike Jones'),
(88, 'Fred Astaire');
insert into messages values
(1, 'Hi how are you?', 55, 0),
(2, 'I have read this', 55, 1),
(3, 'also read this', 55, 1),
(4, 'Another not read', 55, 0),
(5, 'diff user already read', 77, 1),
(6, 'Sup, not read', 88, 0),
(7, 'Partially ready', 88, 1),
(8, 'Not read 88', 88, 0);

select m.msg_status, u.id, u.username
from messages m
join users u on m.msg_from = u.id
order by u.id, m.msg_status;
```

[working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/501a3/1)

Anyway, this does what you're wanting as near as I can tell.  It gives unread messages for users first.  You could flip the order of the order by if you want all unread messages first.
e.g. `order by m.msg_status, u.id`

Comment: Thanks for helping.
I have tried this and its return status 1 for all records. But i want to get first user with message status 0.

Comment: actually this is a messaging system. and i want to show all users who have records in message table and first show unread messages. that we can check with msg_status o or 1